# how to make the vf template editable

Tags: email-template

How can we make a vf template editable,

I tried with contenteditable="true" but the changes were not reflecting in the email.Pls suggest some solution

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="Global Security:{!relatedTo.CaseNumber}" recipientType="User" relatedToType="Case"> 
  <messaging:htmlEmailBody > 
    <p contenteditable="true"> </p> 
  </messaging:htmlEmailBody> 
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

Comment: Can you share some more of what your problem is, the code of your VF template, etc.

Comment: <messaging:emailTemplate  relatedToType="Case">
    <messaging:htmlEmailBody >
    <p contenteditable="true"><insert ur name:> </p>
    </messaging:htmlEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>

Comment: suppose if i give name in the place of <insert ur name:> prior to email sending ,it is not taking the changes what ever i made